# split string after every carriage return or after 125 chars

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a string that is 500 chars long. I need to split the string on every carriage return and after 125 chars. After splitting I would like to insert the splitted string into a table with two columns: one that holds the string and the other that holds an asterisk (*) indicating that the string was a new line.

here is the code that I have so far.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string txt = "The lazy brown fox jumped over the fence. \r\n" +
        "The lazy brown fox jumped over the fence." +
        " The lazy brown fox jumped over the fence. The lazy brown fox jumped over the fence. \r\n" +
        "The lazy brown fox jumped over the fence. The lazy brown fox jumped over the fence. "+
        "The lazy brown fox jumped over the fence.The lazy brown fox jumped over the fence.";


        string[] items = SplitByLength(txt, 124);
        foreach (string item in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }


    }

    private static string[] SplitByLength(string s, int split)
    {
        //Like using List because I can just add to it 
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        // Integer Division
        int TimesThroughTheLoop = s.Length / split;


        for (int i = 0; i < TimesThroughTheLoop; i++)
        {
            list.Add(s.Substring(i * split, split));

        }

        // Pickup the end of the string
        if (TimesThroughTheLoop * split != s.Length)
        {
            list.Add(s.Substring(TimesThroughTheLoop * split));
        }

        return list.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into string.IndexOf().  You can use this to grab the location of any Carriage Returns then decide if you're splitting there or after 125 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like?

```
var lines = txt.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .SelectMany(x => Regex.Matches(x, @".{0,125}(\s+|$)")
                                  .Cast<Match>()
                                  .Select(m => m.Value).ToList())
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot LB for your working example. One more question, how can I remove the white spaces or empty strings?